# Struggling to implement tabs in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to learn Dart and AngularDart. Initially all was good until I decided to try and implement a tab component based on the example similar to the Angular home page e.g.

```html
<tab>
  <panel name="betty">
  Content of betty tab
  </panel>
  <panel name="bob">
  Content of bob tab
  </panel>
</tab>
```

I have implemented following components.

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'tab',
    templateUrl: 'components/tab_component.html',
    cssUrl: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class TabComponent {

    List<TabPanelComponent> panes = new List();

    add(TabPanelComponent tab) {
      panes.add(tab);
    }
}

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'panel',
    templateUrl: 'components/tab_panel.html',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'name': '@name'
    }
)
class TabPanelComponent {

  String name;
  TabComponent tab;

  TabPanelComponent(this.tab) {
    tab.add(this);
  }
}
```

And the following html templates

components/tab_component.html

```html
<div class="tabble">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="pane in ctrl.panes"><a href="#">{{pane.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <content></content>
  </div>

</div>
```

components/tab_panel.html

```html
<div class="tab-pane">
  <content></content>
</div>
```

When run, ctrl.panes in components/tab_component.html is empty, hence the list of tab names are not displayed. I can step through the code and see the panes being added to the list in TabComponent instance and the name attribute being set in the two instances of TabPanelComponent.

I feel that I am close but missing something obvious. Any pointers or advice that someone could offer to help a Dart newbie would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The NgComponent annotation for TabComponent was missing the visibility option. This should be changed from the default to CHILDREN_VISIBILITY

```dart
@NgComponent(
    visibility: NgDirective.CHILDREN_VISIBILITY,
    selector: 'tab',
    templateUrl: 'components/tab_component.html',
    cssUrl: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class TabComponent {
...
```

Comment: What does CHILDREN_VISIBILITY mean?

Comment: I saw that we have two votes for this answer.  When I tried it just now, all I see is:

"Content of betty tab Content of bob tab"

Comment: ... I tried a few other things.  Not working for me.  I am thinking that the example as shown is slightly off-centre. :-)

Comment: I have just tried this again and it appears to be working - but I am no Dart expert :-) I have posted a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/swheeler/9454260) with all of my working files.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to implement a working tab component. Thing is, your approach and my approach are so similar I don't see the difference between them. Nonetheless, here's my working solution:
[code at GitHub](https://github.com/stephanrauh/AngularPrime-Dart/tree/master/lib/puiTabview)